# Variant on classic geometric probability: 3 people meeting during the day

Tags: probability, contest-math

Zeus, Athena, and Poseidon arrive at Mount Olympus at a random time between 12:00 pm and 12:00 am, and stay for 3 hours. All three hours does not need to fall within 12 pm to 12 am. If any of the 2 gods see each other during 12 pm to 12 am, it will be a good day. Find the probability of it being a good day.

You are probably familiar with the classic version of this problem, in which two people meet. It is an exercise in geometric probability. The solution to this problem I believe is a simple extension of the classic method, but for some reason I'm not getting the right answer. Can someone point out the error in my reasoning?:

---

Consider the probability that Zeus and Athena meet between 12 pm and 12 am. Draw a 12 by 12 square with the time at which Zeus arrives at Olympus on the x-axis, and the time at which Athena arrives on the y-axis (lowerleft corner at the origin). This represents all possible combinations of arrival times at Olympus. Note the area is 144. If Zeus arrives at time $t$ hours, Athena must arrive no later than time $t+3$ hours for them to see eachother. Thus draw the lines $y=x+3$,$y=x-3$ and note the area they enclose within the square. The enclosed region represents all possible combinations of arrival times which result in Zeus and Athena seeing each other. The area is $12^2-2(1/2)(9)(9)=63$. So the probability that Zeus and Athena meet is $63/144=7/16$.

We would also like to find the probability that all three gods meet. Draw a 12 by 12 by 12 cube with the time at which Zeus arrives at Olympus on the x-axis, and the time at which Athena arrives on the y-axis, and the time at which Poseidon arrives on the z-axis. Consider the region representing all possible combinations of arrival times that result in all three gods seeing eachother. If we project this region onto the xy, yz, and xz planes, we must get the region described in the paragraph above for the 2D case. Thus the region of interest is the intersection of a triangular prism with the cube and it is symmetric across a space-diagonal of the cube (wish I could show you  a picture). We can find the area by breaking the region up into two right tetrahedrons (at the opposite corners of the cube) and a triangular prism. The volume of each tetrahedrons is $(1/3)bh=(1/3)((1/2)(3)(3))(3)=9/2$ and thus together that $9$. The volume of the prism is $bh$, where $b$ is the area of a triangle with sidelength $3\sqrt{2}$, and $h$ is the length of the space diagonal of the cube, minus twice the height of the corner tetrahedrons. So $b=(3\sqrt{2})^2\sqrt{3}/4=9\sqrt{3}/2$. The volume of each tetrahedron is $9/2=(1/3)(9\sqrt{3}/2)h_1$ so $h_1=\sqrt{3}$. Thus $h=12\sqrt{3}-2\sqrt{3}=10\sqrt{3}$. Thus the volume of the prism is $bh=(9\sqrt{3}/2)(10\sqrt{3})=135$. The total volume of the region is then $135+9=144$. So the probability that all three gods meet is  $144/(12^3)=1/12$.

The final probability then is given by principle of inclusion-exclusion (PIE): $3(7/16)-2(1/12)=55/48$, which is greater than 1. So obviously I am doing something wrong. Can you spot it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the 3-D shapes inside the cube are more complicated than you've allowed for. Let $A,P,Z$ denote Athena, Poseidon, and Zeus, respectively and define the following sets:

\begin{eqnarray*}
AP &=& \{\text{Points where $A$ and $P$ see each other} \} \\
AZ &=& \{\text{Points where $A$ and $Z$ see each other} \} \\
PZ &=& \{\text{Points where $P$ and $Z$ see each other} \}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Then, geometrically, these three sets are as you indicate: a hexagon inside a $12\times 12$ square. Because the other sets we consider will involve 3-D shapes, we could translate this hexagon into 3-D simply by applying it to all possible values for the third god's arrival times giving us a hexagonal prism. Since the area of the hexagon is $63$ as you calculated, the volume of the hexagonal prism is $63\times 12=756$.

$$\\$$

With a view to using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, we look now at the set $AP\cap PZ$ geometrically. As in your working, Zeus's times are on the $x$-axis, Athena's times are on the $y$-axis, and Poseidon's times are on the $z$-axis.

Consider the $xy$-plane for some fixed $z$ between $3$ and $9$. The points in $AP\cap PZ$ are those inside the square bounded by lines:

$$x=z-3;\quad x=z+3;\quad y=z-3;\quad y=z+3.$$

So we have a prism of vertical height $9-3=6$ with a square horizontal cross-section having area $6\times 6=36$. Thus, the volume of this prism is $36\times 6=216$.

Now look at the 3-D shape formed in the corner of the cube as $z$ moves below $3$ and the prism moves outside the cube. It's hard to describe this shape. The boundary of its intersection with the cube surface is the set of lines joining points:

$$(0,0,3);\quad (6,0,3);\quad (3,0,0);\quad (3,3,0);\quad (0,3,0);\quad (0,6,3);\quad (0,0,3).$$

As $z$ reduces, the prism first meets the cube surface when $z=3$, at which point the abovementioned $6\times 6$ square fits neatly in the corner at $(0,0,3)$ of the $z=3$ plane. As $z$ moves further to $0$, this square moves outside the $12\times 12$ square in the horizontal plane, finally becoming a $3\times 3$ square at $z=0$.

For any $0\leq z\leq 3$ the horizontal cross-sectional square has area $(z+3)^2$. The volume of this corner object is then

$$\int_0^3{(z^2+6z+9)\; dz} = \left[ z^3/3 + 3z^2 + 9z \right]_0^3 = 9 + 27 + 27 = 63.$$

The total volume for set $AP\cap PZ$ is therefore, $216+2\times 63 = 342$.

By symmetry, the 3-D shapes for sets $AP\cap AZ$ and $AZ\cap PZ$ have this same volume.

$$\\$$

Now consider the geometry of the set $AP\cap AZ\cap PZ$. In the $xy$-plane for some fixed z between $3$ and $9$, the points in $AP\cap AZ\cap PZ$ are those inside the hexagon bounded by lines:

$$x=z-3;\quad x=z+3;\quad y=z-3;\quad y=z+3;\quad y=x-3;\quad y=x+3.$$

So we have a prism of vertical height $9-3=6$ with a hexagonal horizontal cross-section having area $6^2 - 3^2=27$. Thus, the volume of this prism is $27\times 6=162$.

The object in the corner is again difficult to describe. The boundary of its intersection with the cube surface is the set of lines joining points:

$$(0,0,3);\quad (3,0,3);\quad (3,0,0);\quad (3,3,0);\quad (0,3,0);\quad (0,3,3);\quad (0,0,3).$$

As $z$ reduces, the hexagonal prism first meets the cube surface when $z=3$, at which point the cross-sectional hexagon fits neatly in the corner at $(0,0,3)$ of the $z=3$ plane. As $z$ moves further to $0$, this hexagon moves outside the $12\times 12$ square in the horizontal plane, finally becoming a $3\times 3$ square at $z=0$.

For any $0\leq z\leq 3$ the horizontal cross-sectional hexagon has area $(z+3)^2 - z^2 = 6z+9$. The volume of this corner object is then

$$\int_0^3{(6z+9)\; dz} = \left[3z^2 + 9z \right]_0^3 = 27 + 27 = 54.$$

Therefore the total volume for set $AP\cap AZ\cap PZ$ is $162 + 2\times 54 = 270$.

$$\\$$

Now, using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, we can calulate the volume of the set we require. Here, $|\cdot|$ will denote volume.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\vert AP \cup AZ \cup PZ\vert &=& (\vert AP \vert + \vert AZ \vert + \vert PZ \vert) - (\vert AP\cap AZ \vert + \vert AP\cap PZ \vert + \vert AZ\cap PZ\vert) \\
&& \qquad + \vert AP\cap AZ\cap PZ\vert \\
&=& 3\times 756 - 3\times 342 + 270 \\
&=& 1512.
\end{eqnarray*}

Therefore, the required probability is

$$P(\text{Good day}) = \dfrac{1512}{12^3} = \dfrac{7}{8}.$$

Comment: I will read through your entire solution carefully later. You definitely got the correct answer. So where exactly did I go wrong? What probability did I actually calculate by finding the volume of the 3D object?

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou You got the first part right with the hexagon in the square. The second part was wrong: the prism is not triangular, nor is the corner object a tetrahedron. I hope my answer explains why. Also, there are 2 types of 3D objects rather than 1, when we intersect. IE Principle asks us, for example, to look at $AZ\cap PZ$ and $AZ\cap PZ\cap AP$. These are different objects/sets. $AZ\cap PZ$ says both $A$ and $P$ must see $Z$ but not necessarily see each other, whereas $AZ\cap PZ\cap AP$ says each god sees both the other two. Thus, geometrically, these are different objects.